# How to create a single color image using ImageView in android programmatically?

Tags: android, uiimageview

Is there any way to create an image using ImageView containing a solid single color programmatically?

Comment: Using canvas you can draw an image...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use View or if you want to use `ImageView` then you can use any single color image in background.

```
<View
   android:id="@+id/view_image"
   android:layout_width="100dp"
   android:layout_height="100dp"
   android:background="#ff0000 />
```

With help of view **id** you can change color at any instance like this.

**From Java(programatically)**

```
View singlecolorImage= (View) findViewById(R.id.linear);
singlecolorImage.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorPrimary));
```

Comment: Thanks... Creating a view object works but I am unable to understand if I instead create an ImageView, Framelayout,etc.. object it doesn't work...

Comment: @HarshGupta the view is worked  just because of static hight & width

Answer (score 1):

You do not need `ImageView` for that. Any view (i.e. `FrameLayout`) will do as long as you set its background color to what you need using just `setBackgroundColor()` or XML `android:background` attribute, i.e.

```
<FrameLayout
   android:layout_width="100dp"
   android:layout_height="100dp"
   android:background="#ff0000 />
```

Comment: I am not getting anything on the screen by creating a framelayout or linearlayout object.. but simply creating a View object does it for me.. I am unable to understand why...

Comment: as @HarshGupta reported its not working in this case. so i think upvote not required..

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

*Initialize a new Bitmap object*

```
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                        500, // Width
                        300, // Height
                        Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888 // Config
                );
```

*Initialize a new Canvas instance*

```
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
```

*Draw a solid color to the canvas background*

```
canvas.drawColor(Color.LTGRAY);
```

*Initialize a new Paint instance to draw the Circle*

```
Paint paint = new Paint();
                paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
                paint.setColor(Color.RED);
                paint.setAntiAlias(true);
```

*Calculate the available radius of canvas*

```
int radius = Math.min(canvas.getWidth(),canvas.getHeight()/2);
```

*Set a pixels value to padding around the circle*

```
int padding = 5;
```

*Finally, draw the circle on the canvas*

```
canvas.drawCircle(
                        canvas.getWidth() / 2, // cx
                        canvas.getHeight() / 2, // cy
                        radius - padding, // Radius
                        paint // Paint
                );
```

*Display the newly created bitmap on app interface*

```
mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```